# Java dashboard login error

Tags: java

I have been doing the java project. I am faced with the trouble in dashboard login code. I have the login code as belows.

```
String fieldtxtname=txtusername.getText();
String fieldtxtpw=txtpassword.getText();
String fieldtxtutype=txttypeof.getText();
try{

    Connection cnn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student","root","");
    Statement stm=cnn.createStatement();

    String sqlQuery="select username,password,typeof from tbl_user";

    ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

      while(rs.next()){
        String unamedb=rs.getString("username");
        String pworddb=rs.getString("password");
        String tofdb=rs.getString("typeof");
         if(fieldtxtname.equals ("")||fieldtxtpw.equals ("")||fieldtxtutype.equals ("")){
            System.out.println("The fields arenot filled properly");
            }
          else if(fieldtxtname.equals(unamedb)&&fieldtxtpw.equals(pworddb)&&fieldtxtutype.equals(tofdb)){
            System.out.println("Access granted");
            }
         else
            {
            System.out.println("Unknown username"); 
            }


      } 

}
catch(SQLException ex){
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

The code works fine except that when the access in granted,it prints as

```
 Access granted
    Unknown username
    Unknown username
    Unknown username
    Unknown username
```

Similar is the case when the fields are empty i.e they print five timesvlike belows.

```
The fields arenot filled properly
The fields arenot filled properly
The fields arenot filled properly
The fields arenot filled properly
The fields arenot filled properly
```

.I am not figuring out the cause of the problem.Please help and I would like to thank a lot in advance.

Comment: What do you want exactly . Do you want to print only one time in console?

Comment: @pallavidestiny22 your `ResultSet` consists of 5 elements, so iteration continues for 5 times. Ideally for a unique combination of username and password I would expect it to return just 1 element. What do you expect the behaviour to be if the `username` and `password` found to be correct or empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding comments to the current code implementation that you've posted and how you can overcome printing multiple times on the output.

```
ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery(sqlQuery); // this is returning 5 elements

while(rs.next()) {
    String unamedb=rs.getString("username");
    String pworddb=rs.getString("password");
    String tofdb=rs.getString("typeof");
    if(fieldtxtname.equals ("")||fieldtxtpw.equals ("")||fieldtxtutype.equals ("")){
        System.out.println("The fields are not filled properly.");
        break;
// you might want to break the loop if the fields are empty in db
    } else if(fieldtxtname.equals(unamedb)&&fieldtxtpw.equals(pworddb)&&fieldtxtutype.equals(tofdb)) {
        System.out.println("Access granted");
        break;
// you might want to break the loop once the username, passwrod is found for access to be granted
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unknown username"); // just to display information
    }
}
```

*PS -  Ideally for a unique combination of username and password I would expect it to return just 1 element.*

Edit - For using `PreparedStatement` to solve the above without using the loop, do look at the [answer from @Arvind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41085105/1746118)

Comment: incase all fileds are filled but not proper username,pw and typeof,stilll it is printing "Unknown username" five times.

Comment: Shall i put break in the last else statement also

Comment: needed break for the final else as well, anyone i would greatly appreciate ur help

Comment: if you do that, and the first two conditions are also not met, you would anyway exit the loop after the first iteration. As I said not sure why the `ResultSet` would consist of 5 element. But if you want to check all 5 of them then you should go about not introducing the break at last `else`. You need to decide on whether the ResultSet should return 1 or 5 elements.

Comment: i want resultset to return only one row

Comment: If that strictly confirms you shouldn't need the `while` loop as well and eventually get rid of the `break` statements as well.

Comment: i want to know in the else, the results equivalent to no of rows in table in printing

Comment: then you might just want to continue using the `while` loop to iterate all rows  as in the answer above.

Comment: It consumes more time to fetch the resultset when size of the table gets increases.. you need to use the where condition in your query

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't add your three parameter (fieldtxtname,fieldtxtpw,fieldtxtutype) to your query in where clause as bind variables!

```
 String fieldtxtname=txtusername.getText();
    String fieldtxtpw=txtpassword.getText();
    String fieldtxtutype=txttypeof.getText();
    if(fieldtxtname.equals ("")||fieldtxtpw.equals ("")||fieldtxtutype.equals ("")){
        System.out.println("The fields arenot filled properly");
        return;
    }

    try{

        Connection cnn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student","root","");

        PreparedStatement pstm = cnn.prepareStatement("select username,password,typeof from tbl_user where username= ? and password= ? and typeof  = ?");
        pstm.setString(1, fieldtxtname);
        pstm.setString(2, fieldtxtpw);
        pstm.setString(3, fieldtxtutype);

        ResultSet rs=pstm.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println("Access granted");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Access not granted");

    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

Comment: Correct way, I agree

Comment: could you elaborate  more

Comment: you must change your procedure:

Comment: please show the jdbc connection with preparestatement, i am newbie and amnot getting the jdbc connection with PreparedStatement

Comment: This code will print always Access granted for unknown user also

Comment: No, if your user with these (fieldtxtname, fieldtxtpw, fieldtxtutype) information exists in DB, then print Access Granted else Access not granted

Comment: you are executing the stm not prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

You must perform **validation** before **authentication**, i.e. before you connect to db check if all mandatory fields are filled by user.

```
String fieldtxtname=txtusername.getText();
String fieldtxtpw=txtpassword.getText();
String fieldtxtutype=txttypeof.getText();
//validation
if(fieldtxtname.isEmpty()||fieldtxtpw.isEmpty()||fieldtxtutype.isEmpty()){
  System.err.println("All fields are mandatory !");
}else{
  //authentication
  try{
    Connection cnn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student","root","");

    //just get one row based user input, why to get same column values, when user is gonna give same input?
    String sqlQuery="select 1 from tbl_user where username=? and password=? and typeof=?";

    // Prefer `PreparedStatement` over `Statement`, when you have runtime values for sql queries, this for avoiding SQL injection
    PreparedStatement ps = cnn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
    ps.setString(1,fieldtxtname);
    ps.setString(2,fieldtxtpw);
    ps.setString(3,fieldtxtutype);
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

    if(rs.next()){//no need of loop
        System.out.println("Access Granted ...");
    }else{
        System.err.println("Access Denied !");
    }

    rs.close();
    ps.close();
    cnn.close();
  }catch(SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use where condition in your query. It will help you to execute your query fast compared to your's, i.e without where condition.

```
String fieldtxtname=txtusername.getText();
String fieldtxtpw=txtpassword.getText();
String fieldtxtutype=txttypeof.getText();
    if(fieldtxtname.equals ("")||fieldtxtpw.equals ("")||fieldtxtutype.equals ("")){
        System.out.println("The fields are not filled properly");
    }else{
    try{
        Connection cnn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student","root","");
        Statement stm=cnn.createStatement();
        String sqlQuery="select username,password,typeof from tbl_user where username="+fieldtxtname+",password="+fieldtxtpw+",typeof="+fieldtxtutype;
        ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
        boolean flag=true;
        while(rs.next()){
            flag=false;
            System.out.println("Access granted");
        } 
        if(flag){
            System.out.println("Unknown username"); 
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```